# Mongoose/NodeJS defining static/method for saving a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to define my own static/method do save a document of my model.

I've tried this:

```
userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
    data.save(callback);
};
```

It says data.save() is not a function. It doesn't recognize the function.

Then i tried this

```
userSchema.statics.saveUser = function(data, callback){
    data = new userSchema(data);
    data.save(callback);
};
```

userSchema is not a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods and statics are not the same. The former are found on documents (model instances) while the latter on the model. If the above is intended to be used as a static, creating a user or something, you would:

```
userModel.saveUser();
```

However I don't really see what good that would do as you're not passing it any data. If you instead create it as a method it would look like this:

```
userSchema.methods.saveUser = function(callback){
    user.save(callback);
};
```

And you would call it like:

```
var doc = new userModel();
// Set stuff
doc.saveUser();
```

Without knowing what you actually want to do it's hard to say which way is preferable in your case.

Comment: I get an error at 'user = new this()' => "object is not a function"

Comment: Oh sorry it doesn't need to run new this() since you already has created a new document yourself. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Statics are used when you want to do model-related stuff (like "findAllByFirstName")
They are not for interacting with an instance of a model (user would be an instance of your model)

If you want to save an instance of a model into mongo then methods are the way to go.

Comment: How would a method like this look like?

Answer (score 1):

may be you wanna do somethig like this:

```
schema.statics.user = function() {
    var model = this.model("user");
    return {
        login:require('./resources/user/login.js'),
        signin:require('./resources/user/signin.js')
    }
}
var model = mongoose.model("<name>",schema);
var user = model.user();
user.login(...)
user.signin(...)
```